# How to move the last n files in hdfs

Tags: xargs, hadoop, hdfs

I have a folder in HDFS contains 830000 files, and I want to move the last "8797" files enter code here to another folder in HDFS? I tried using xargs but didn't work fine. Any other ideas?

Here is the exact split point between all files. I want to move files after "2021-03-09 15:15"

`-rw-rw-r--+  3 talend_user talend_group     102013 2021-03-09 15:14 /user/file_1`

`-rw-rw-r--+  3 talend_user talend_group       9360 2021-03-09 15:15 /user/file_2`

Comment: Last, in what sense?

Comment: What command did you use and what didn't work? Add that and a sample of the files to the question.

Comment: Please reread and see the edits in the question

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean "8797 most recently modified files". With `zsh` that would be easily done with `mv /user/*(.om[1,8797]) /destdir` but I don't know anything about HDFS so I can't give a clear answer.  It's unclear _how_ you tried doing this with `xargs`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, actually it is easy in local file system to do it using "find" command, but in HDFS is it not direct. I think I am downloading all files to local system, do the split, and reupload them to hdfs again in the desired folders.

Comment: What hadoop version are you running?